# Loadrunner 12.53, Fiori, Web HTTP Html protocol execution slow

Tags: html, json, http, loadrunner

i am debugging script in vugen with 12.53 version of loadrunner ( designed with web http/html)protocol. Issue is that the execution takes long long time! may be greateer than 30 minutes which isn not the case when checked the applocation manually. I am exeucting this script on a remote VM with windows 2012 R2 OS.
Any clue, appreciated
Thank you.

Comment: issue got solved. i changed the replay settings (from socket to winnet)option

Comment: See license agreement regarding remote access when not using Performance Center.  This can place the license holder at extreme risk in an audit